# timer wont stop running in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quiz in JavaScript and I set a timer for the intro page after the timer the question pops up and the intro page disappears but after I answer the first question the second question shows up momentarily and then it's gone and restarts the webpage all over again, how do I fix this. the code is provided below

```js
let timeLeft = 5; // Set the initial countdown time in seconds
let currentQuestionIndex = 0;
let don = false
function countdown() {
    if(don === false){
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
        timeLeft--;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerText = timeLeft;

        // Check if the continue button was clicked
        const continueButtonClicked = document.getElementById("nextButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Hide the intro section
            document.getElementById("introSection").style.display = "none";
            // Show the question section
            document.getElementById("questionSection").style.display = "block";
            don = true;
            // Start the countdown
            setInterval(countdown, 1000);
        });
    }
    } if (timeLeft == 0) {
        // Time's up, show the "Next" button or perform other actions
        document.getElementById("introSection").style.display = "none";
        // Show the question section
        document.getElementById("questionSection").style.display = "block";
        don = true;
    }
}
let questions = [];
questions.push({ Question: "What school do we go to?", a: "MTU", b: "ATU", c: "CIT", d: "LIT" });
questions.push({ Question: "What is 2 + 2?", a: "3", b: "4", c: "5", d: "6" });

// Display the first question
displayQuestion();

function displayQuestion() {
    let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
    document.getElementById("question").innerText = currentQuestion.Question;
    document.getElementById("labelA").innerText = currentQuestion.a;
    document.getElementById("labelB").innerText = currentQuestion.b;
    document.getElementById("labelC").innerText = currentQuestion.c;
    document.getElementById("labelD").innerText = currentQuestion.d;
}
function nextQuestion() {
    don = true;
    // Move to the next question
    currentQuestionIndex++;

    // Check if there are more questions
    if (currentQuestionIndex < 3) {
        // Display the next question
        displayQuestion();
    }
}

// Start the countdown
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="start" id="introSection">
        <h1><u>Welcome to my Quiz</u></h1>
        <p class="start-text">Welcome to my client-side scripting Quiz.
            There will be ten questions you will have to answer, and your 
            results will be shown to you after you have finished the Quiz.
            Best of luck!<br><br>
            You can press "Continue" or wait for the page to load on its own.
        </p> 
        <div id="countdown">5</div>
        <button id="nextButton" onclick="startQuiz()">Continue</button>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="questionSection" style="display:none;">
        <h2 id="question"></h2>
        <form id="quizForm">
        <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="a" id="optionA"> <span id="labelA"></span></label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="b" id="optionB"> <span id="labelB"></span></label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="c" id="optionC"> <span id="labelC"></span></label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="d" id="optionD"> <span id="labelD"></span></label><br>
        <button id="nextQuestionButton" onclick="nextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script src="ScriptingFinal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `.addEventListener()` method **adds** listeners without removing any listeners already present. Thus you're adding that "click" handler over and over again. When the button is clicked, **all** of the handlers will run.

Comment: look at the doc => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval ...

Comment: you `Start the countdown` in two places, and never stop it anywhere - an interval repeatedly calls the callback function until it is stopped - you have potentially 2 or more intervals calling the same callback - and every time you click continue, the problem increases exponentially

Comment: Your `timer` is not the problem. Since it's counting down and displaying the question. The problem is with the `nextQuestionButton` since it is clicked for the first question and since the second question has the same `ID` the second question is also pressed.

Comment: Dude, I strongly suggest to handle time (specially for a quiz) on the server, so clients cannot crack it.